# Using Serilog, I have implemented logging into multiple files but fileSizeLimitBytes not working

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore, serilog-filter

I am already logging into an API file and would like to log into a different file for just one class. Therefore I used Filter.ByIncludingOnly to accomplish this, and it is working as expected.

However, it does not take into account the '**fileSizeLimitBytes**' property. Once it reaches a size of 98 KB, it creates another file. is there any other way to achieve it?

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
         .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
         .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
           .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(evt => evt.Properties.ContainsKey("SourceContext")
                && evt.Properties["SourceContext"].ToString().Contains("Web.Core.Helpers.ExcelReader"))
            .WriteTo.Map("Name", "import", (name, wt) => wt.File($"./Logs/log-{name}-.txt",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                fileSizeLimitBytes: 200000, // File size limit for the 'import' key
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                retainedFileCountLimit: 60)))
         .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
            .WriteTo.Map("Name", "api", (name, wt) => wt.File($"./Logs/log-{name}-.txt",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                fileSizeLimitBytes: 100000,
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                retainedFileCountLimit: 60)))
         .CreateLogger();
```

[image: log images]

Comment: 100,000 bytes = 97.7Kb. All the *api*.text files adhere to this except the first one.  The *import*.txt file is only 33Kb so it won't roll over until 195.3Kb.  What am I missing?

Comment: @BTSoft sorry, take into accout log-api files as they rolled over to new files once they are 98 kb

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is you are facing. You defined two different log files with different max size constraints. As far as I can tell, serilog is doing exactly what you have configured it to do. Please be extremely specific as to what you are expecting to see happen and how that is different from what is happening.